# Placing an ASP.NET ImageButton inside a TableCell

Tags: asp.net, imagebutton

I'm trying to put an imagebutton in a tablecell, but the only property to add *anything* to a tablecell I know of, is the Text property. And that's for text, only accepting Strings.

How do I add the Imagebutton instance instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tableCell.Controls.Add(imageButtonInstance);
```